# Correct place for responding to user input

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this ASP .Net app where I want to respond to user input to generate a new page. In the aspx, I have a number of buttons and other controls that allow him to make choices of what he wants to see. They have onclick-type handlers to code-behind procedures.

Now what I want is:
- Process those choices into all kinds of parameters and variables and 
- Databind to the database (based on those parms and variables)

Originally, I thought this should be done in Page_load, but that was a terrible mistake and I made a huge mess of my code now. I'm trying to fix it now, but I find that I'm coding all that first-bullet-stuff in each individual event handler (i.e., the "FillParametersForDatabaseAccess" type stuff).

This is obviously a pain in the a$$ and error-prone in the long run... so I'm wondering, in which part of the code should I code this? I'm looking for a generic place that happens AFTER the event handlers from the aspx are processed ("onclick"-type stuff), but BEFORE the databind of any data-aware controls... what to use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've done a fair amount of coding in asp.net webpages and I think that if the action you want to take is specific to the button it should be put in the button click handler. If the things to do in the buttons are the same, the different button handlers can call the same method. (As I see it ASP:Net webpages porgramming is a pain in the *** I like MVC or MVD + angular (or JQuery) frontend  better)

Comment: Try using the `protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)` event. It is one of the last events raised as part of the page processing. You can still databind controls etc based on state changes in previous events in the page though.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, the event I meant is LoadComplete.